# '@sailshq/socket.io-redis@latest' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

**Node version**: 10.16.0
**Sails version** *(sails)*: 1.2.3

---

When I try to create new project using sails cli it just gives me below error and I can not do anything.

And I see there is a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis but it doesn't have `@sailshq` prefix in the package name.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@sailshq%2fsocket.io-redis - Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@sailshq/socket.io-redis@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: [@sailshq/socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sailshq/socket.io-redis) works for me

Comment: What version of sails and what commands are you using with sails cli to generate a new app? Typically `sails new your-app-name` should work ([options](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-new)).  You might try updating @sailshq/socket.io-redis `npm i @sailshq/socket.io-redis` and npm `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Comment: @johnabrams7 turn out it was my node.. I uninstalled and installed again and it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: @SagarKhatri - interesting! Good to know, glad that fixed it.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, using node v12.13.0 and npm v6.12.0. Anyone figure out a way to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `npm i @sailshq/socket.io-redis`?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sailshq/socket.io-redis

Comment: turn out it was my node.. I uninstalled and installed again and it worked. Thanks for your help